# Query folding for Mysql in Power Query

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerquery

My data sits in mysql and I want to use incremental refresh in my power bi report. But I need foldable queries to use this incremental refresh feature.
I have come across this function - Value.NativeQuery(), but seems like it works for sql server and postgresql only.How can I convert native queries of Mysql in power query (Power BI) to foldable queries?

How can I convert native queries of Mysql in power query (Power BI) to foldable queries?

Answer (score 0):

According to Power BI documentation on [folding native queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding?source=recommendations), only the following connectors support folding native queries:

- Amazon Redshift
- Dataverse (when using enhanced compute)
- Google BigQuery
- PostgreSQL
- SAP HANA
- Snowflake
- SQL Server

Mysql is not listed among them at the moment, so you need to look for alternative ways to make a query foldable.